# Error when building once built java web project?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, persistence

When I run for the first time there doesn't show any errors and I did double check the code and there is no error, but once again when I build the file again the following error pops up.

```
Deleting directory C:\Users\Vbabey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PersistenceMYEX2\build C:\Users\Vbabey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PersistenceMYEX2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1054: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Vbabey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PersistenceMYEX2\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\toplink-essentials-agent.jar
```

I cannot understand the reason for the above error? Can anybody explain me what it is?

Comment: Have you checked if other services is using toplink-essentials-agent.jar?

Comment: Ah I didn't can you please tell me how can I do that, because, I am a beginner in this section?

Comment: Does it exhibit the same behavior if you run ant from outside of Eclipse?  It could be a bug in one of the tasks that you are using that is keeping a reference to the file open.

Comment: And when I restart the server, the building error never pops up...I cannot understand why?

Comment: I am using netbeans and I am sorry I have no good experience in using ANT, I am following some tutorials...

Comment: Don't worry about having less experience. Asking questions means you want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you are running into the default windows locking behavior.  If you have a jar file open to run an application, you can't overwrite it.

Comment: Ok then what is the action that I can take in order to get rid of this problem?

Comment: It looks like there's no practical way for you to do it -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546504/how-do-i-make-windows-file-locking-more-like-unix-file-locking on a discussion of what it would take to disable the behavior, which given your question won't be something you can do.

Comment: you could try adding failonerror="false" to the ant task, but it'll likely just fail later in the build process when it tries to create the .jar file

Answer (score 0):

You might be building it when the server is on. Some other application is using your files.
Try switching off the server or other applications that may be using the files.

A quick fix can be to export the project and import it with a different name and then you can build it.

Comment: Yeah I am doing similar thing...but is there any permanent remedy for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply stop the tomcat or kill the java.exe process before building again.
2. Secondly, I believe you're using Clean & Build option, which does create issue, when the project is already running. Instead just use the build option or run option in case you want to run.